# Activity wihtout layout - hide navigation bar

Tags: java, android, hide, navbar

I have an activity (splash) without any layout (setContentView never called). I want to hide both status bar and navigation bar and make it full screen. I tried this inside `onCreate`:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

But it has no effect. Is there any other method? I have also tried to to apply some flags inside theme definition:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>
```

But, only status bar is hidden, navbar is still visible.

Comment: i test your code and it worked for me! What is the Android version of your device?

Comment: Doesn't your activity include layout? It should have no layout at all (only background set via theme) and it's also launcher activity.